# how to set up background view update in durandal

Tags: durandal

I develop some admin pannel in durandal and have some view which show actively mutating data.

How can i force this view to repeatedly update, say, once in T seconds?

just give me a link to some sample/doc page/methods.

thanks

Comment: You need to tell us what you have tried so far, show some code, and tell us where your data is coming from.  How does it mutate and come to mutate, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you will use observable variables (which are part of KnockoutJs, and part of Durandal) in your application - you will see changes immediately. [**KnockoutJs Observables Documentation**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)

If you are already use observables but need to make some delay between updating observable and refreshing UI - you can use [**Rate-limiting observable notifications**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html) which are delaying update notification for observable variables.